# Two way communications in .Net remoting

Tags: .net, remoting

Once the communication between Client and Server is created, the Client could call the remote object functions through proxy. Under this situation, is it possible that Server could call functions reside in Client side? If so, in what way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished this through events. Its not exactly what you are asking, but the client can access the remote object on the server, it can also add event handlers. This way when the server wants to notify the client of something or send it a message, it can raise an event.

If you search [.Net Remoting Events](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net+remoting+events) you will come up with a lot. Its been a lot of years since I have built a system that uses remoting so I can't recall all of the details.

Here is the classic chat room example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/remotingandevents.aspx